# How to change the base in radix sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I made a radix sort (lsd) program that works with base 10, but i don’t understand how to use it with a different one.

Code:

```
async function radix(array, nb) {
    let group = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    let array2 = {};

    let res = [];

    let loop = -1

    for (let elt of array) {
        console.log(loop)
        loop++;
        checks++;
        draw(array, sound=false)

        osc.stop()

        osc = playSound(array[loop] * 2);
      
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'
        ctx.fillRect(loop * canvas.width / array.length, canvas.height - array[loop], canvas.width / array.length, array[loop]);

        let __ = await(sleep(wait_time))

        for (let i of group) {
            if (elt.length >= nb) {
                if (elt[elt.length - nb - 1] == i) {
                    array2[elt] = i;
                }
            } else if (elt[0] == i) {
                array2[elt] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    for (let nb = 0; nb < 10; nb++) {
        for (let key in array2) {
            if (array2[key] == nb) {
                res.push(parseInt(key))
                draw(merge(res, remv(array, res.length)))

                console.log(merge(res, remv(array, res.length)))
              
                //draw(res)
                if (nb % 1 == 0) {
                  let __ = await sleep(0.00001);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  return res;
}
```

I tried to divide the numbers by the base, but it didn’t work and i don’t understand how to make it work.

Comment: That's a lot more than a simple radix sort. For example, in a typical sorting process, there's no need to "draw" anything.

Comment: The draw function is just to visualize the array

Comment: Actually, i think i don’t have to modify the radix sort, just change the initial values to a different base

Answer (score 0):

The choice of base in the radix sort is arbitrary, and results are going to be same for any base. It just affects the balance between the loop count and storage size.

```js
function radixSort(a, base) {
    let shift = 1

    while (1) {
        let buckets = []

        for (let i = 0; i < base; i++)
            buckets[i] = []

        for (let n of a) {
            let digit = ((n / shift) | 0) % base
            buckets[digit].push(n)
        }

        if (buckets[0].length === a.length)
            break

        a = buckets.flat()
        shift *= base
    }

    return a
}


a = radixSort([170, 45, 75, 90, 2, 802, 2, 66], 10)
console.log(...a)

a = radixSort([170, 45, 75, 90, 2, 802, 2, 66], 5)
console.log(...a)
```